# HtmlAgilityPack - Get only the first match

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, html-agility-pack

Im new to HtmlAgilityPack and i cant figure out how to stop the search after the first match has been found.

```
Dim site As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb = New HtmlWeb()
Dim document As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument = site.Load("website")

For Each table As HtmlNode In document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='forum_thread_post']//a[@href]")
        ListBox1.Items.Add(table.InnerText)
Next
```

The problem is that the website contains many td[@class='forum_thread_post' nodes and i only need the first one. I experimented with SelectSingleNode too, but i couldnt even get that to work but im thinking that is the way to do it? If getting the single match to a textbox is better/easier i would want that.

Here is a picture: http://oi42.tinypic.com/25fmwr5.jpg
I want to get the a title or a alt from the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was wrong with `SelectSingleNode`?

```
Dim table = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='forum_thread_post']//a[@href]")
ListBox1.Items.Add(table.InnerText)
```

If the `InnerText` could be empty:

```
Dim tables = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='forum_thread_post']//a[@href]")
Dim firstNotEmpty = tables.FirstOrDefault(Function(t) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.InnerText))
```

Comment: i tried something similar to this, but it doesnt find any results and the listbox remains empty...

Comment: Oh... maybe the problem is that the first result it gets is a empty line.. because with the old code, it gave me one empty line and the second line was the one i needed?

Comment: @rip2444: That could be,  use the debugger and you'll be wiser.

Comment: Well debugger also confirmed this... the first table.InnerText result is "" (empty line) and the second result shows text. But how exactly should i try to fix that?

Comment: It says FirstOrDefault is not a member of HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection

Comment: Then you need to use Descendents to be able to use Linq. I cannot test it anymore since I'm writing on a phone now.

Comment: Im going to make a new project file with higher framework to get ling and try the previous code out

Comment: Im using framework 4.5 now, the previous errors are gone now, but now it says InnerText is not a member of HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection at (table.InnerText). If i put the code into a For Each statement the error goes away, but the old FirstOrDefault error comes back...

Comment: lol... i was so tired, after a small nap i looked at the code again and figured out that all i had to do was ListBox1.Items.Add(firstNotEmpty.InnerText). Anyways it works perfectly... so stupid of me